# public key ssl error when try to connect to mysql

Tags: mysql, rundeck

In my laboratory I use rundeck to schedule the execution of my scripts, and rundeck uses mysql 8 as a database, but recently rundeck cannot start due to the following error:
"java.sql.SQLTransientConnectionException: Could not connect to address=(host=localhost)(port=3306)(type=master) : RSA public key is not available client side (option serverRsaPublicKeyFile not set)"

However, I have already made the settings in both rundeck and mysql so as not to request SSL for the connection.

MYSQL:

SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'require_secure_transport';

+--------------------------+-------+

| Variable_name                   | Value |

+--------------------------+-------+

| require_secure_transport | OFF   |

+--------------------------+-------+

1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'ssl%';

+---------------------------+-------+

| Variable_name             | Value |

+---------------------------+-------+

| ssl_ca                    |       |

| ssl_capath                |       |

| ssl_cert                  |       |

| ssl_cipher                |       |

| ssl_crl                   |       |

| ssl_crlpath               |       |

| ssl_fips_mode             | OFF   |

| **ssl_key**                   |       |

| ssl_session_cache_mode    | ON    |

| ssl_session_cache_timeout | 300   |

+---------------------------+-------+

10 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> SHOW VARIABLES LIKE '%ssl';

+---------------+----------+

| Variable_name | Value |

+---------------+----------+

| have_openssl  | **DISABLED **|

| have_ssl      | **DISABLED **|

+---------------+----------+

2 rows in set (0.00 sec)

RUNDECK:

dataSource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost/rundeck?autoReconnect=true&**useSSL=false**

Any ideas to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the following param in your datasource string: `allowPublicKeyRetrieval=true`

Like this:

`dataSource.url=jdbc:mariadb://mysql/rundeck?autoReconnect=true&useSSL=false&allowPublicKeyRetrieval=true`

Additionally, if you're using a recent version of Rundeck, the MariaDB jdbc driver is the default driver for MySQL and MariaDB backends.

Check [this](https://github.com/rundeck/welcome-project-community/blob/main/docker-compose.yml#L16) example.